# Why use npm with laravel?

Tags: php, node.js, npm, laravel-5

As npm is the package manager for node, I frequently see it used with laravel boilerplate projects, but I can't reason why?

For example, this [laravel-5-boilerplate](https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-5-boilerplate) instructs to `npm install` within the steps of installing the project..

Other examples too can be found of using npm with laravel..

Can someone please explain to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Blockquote
>
> I made that boilerplate. That command is specific to download the
>   dependencies for the Laravel Elixir package
>   (http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/elixir) But has many, many uses outside
>   that.

The Elixir docs explain it very well.

Comment: Thanks Anthony for explanation, so basically npm will install js packages? like we can find useful packages for angular js too?

Answer (score 8):

Nowadays `npm` containing general tools for work with various front-end tasks. So, it's very useful to grab some packages from it. In case of laravel, there is two utilities, that it uses:

[**gulp**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp) - streaming building tool for concatenating, minifing your css,js code.

[**laravel-elixir**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-elixir) - is wrapper for gulp, written by Jeffrey Way, who is doing laracasts for us. It's place where you can found out more about this this tool in [particular](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5/episodes/10) and in [common](https://laracasts.com/lessons).

If you will use only standart js/css, you can pass this step.